# Angular frequency integral to wavelength integral

Tags: frequency, integration, wavelength

I have this integral
$$
\bar{\omega}^2 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\omega^2|\tilde{F}(j\omega)|^2\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
$$
and I want to convert it to wavelength domain $\lambda $.
I know that the realtion between $\omega$ to $\lambda$ is
$$
\omega = \frac{2\pi c}{\lambda}
$$
so 
$$
d\omega = -\frac{2\pi c}{\lambda^2}d\lambda
$$
where $\tilde{F}(j\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of a Gaussian. Then I plugged those relations and I get 
$$
\bar{\lambda}^2 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{16\pi^4c^3}{\lambda^4}|\tilde{F}(\lambda)|^2d\lambda
$$ 
If it is right what are the boundaries of the integral?